# Open link in new tab - Pop-up Blocked

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, popups

Why does Chromium block <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> any link on http://www.amd.com as if it were a pop-up?

Using: Chromium 44.0.2403.89 in Ubuntu 15.04 (no extensions)

Also, I noticed this on other pages as well (including some links on http://www.cnn.com).

Note: The issue is also posted here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=531549

Comment: I get the same behavior in Windows 7 (Chromium 45.0.2454.85).

Comment: I'm not seeing anything unusual with Ctrl+Click in Google Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit) with www.amd.com. Links open in new tabs as expected. Maybe Ubuntu's Chromium 44 is a bit odd?

Comment: I also witnessed this behavior which tells me the behavior is limited to amd.com.  As for the reason I would assume its a misbehaving code on their website causing it.

Comment: http://www.amd.com perfectly works on firefox and opera. So the fault should be in chrome, not in the website.

Comment: Curiously, this only happens when you ctl-click (since I'm on a Mac, it's Cmd-click). It doesn't happen when you right-click and select Open in a new Window. So I suspect there's Javascript that's specifically catching the event sent with ctl-click.

Comment: Not putting this as an answer because I haven't actually tested it, but I found the following JavaScript function name in the code for the site: `AjaxNavigate$WantsNewTab`.  It seems that AMD is trying to do something fancy with page navigation (maybe similar to GitHub's [pjax](http://pjax.herokuapp.com/) technology) and is catching the Control key.

Comment: So frustrating and this has been a problem for YEARS! I'm going to try Firefox.

Comment: This issue goes way back to 2013 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=305351

Answer (score 2):

Per the same link you provided, this has already been recognized as an issue by the Chromium team and is under investigation.

The only likely fix until resolved by the Chromium developers is globally whitelisting `*.amd.com` in Chrome. To do this:

1. Click `Manage Pop-up blocking...` in Chrome's popup notification.
2. In the text entry field at the bottom of the window, type in `*.amd.com` and ensure the Behavior option is set to Allow.